# Prove that the closure of a set equals the intersection of all closed sets containing it.

Tags: real-analysis

I do think that the answer is easy but I need help in writing a proper proof.

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, and $A,B \subset E$ then:

Prove $\bar A$ coincides with the intersection of the set of all subsets $F \subset E$ such that $F$ contains $A$ and $F$ is closed set in $E.$

Comment: What is a Closer?

Comment: @YujieZha { if x belong to E : for each r>0, b(x,r) ∩ A ≠ Φ}

Comment: Ok, according to the new edit, I do see we call it closure more often. First time I see closer to be honest

Comment: What does B have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the intersection of all closed sets in $E$ that contain the set $A.$ Then, as $\bar A$ is closed and contains $A,$ it follows that $B \subset \bar A.$ For the reverse, if $x$ belong to the closure of $A$ in $E$ and $F$ is a closed set in $E$ that contains $A,$ then for every $r > 0,$ the ball $B(x, r)$ intersects $A$ and therefore, $F$ too, hence $x \in B.$ QED

Comment: What dose QED mean ?

Comment: Quod Erat Demonstrandum, "what was to be shown", in Latin. Somewhat uncommon nowadays, but it used to be a signature way of ending a proof.

Comment: Thanks alot , i have another small question should I write another question or can i ask it directly to you ?

Comment: If it is short, go on. Comments have a limit of a couple of lines.

Comment: co( A∪B)=co(A) ∪ co(B) "co is the closer "

Comment: The original question of this post states that the closure (NOT closer) is the _smallest_ closed set containing $A.$ You probably know that union of closed sets is closed. From this two, deduce the equality (one inclusion: $co(A) \cup co(B)$ is closed containing $A \cup B,$ hence its closure; the other inclusion: $co(A \cup B)$ is closed containing $A,$ hence its closure, similarly for $B$ and so, it contains the union. (Details left to you).

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \subset E$ and let $F_\alpha$ be closed in E for each $\alpha$ in a non-empty index set I.

Let $A \subset F_\alpha \,\, \forall \alpha \in I$

Let $\bar{A}$ be the closure of A in E. Since $\bar{A} \subset F_\alpha \,\, \forall \alpha \in I$ then $\bar{A} \cap F_\alpha = \bar{A} \,\, \forall \alpha \in I$. This implies $(\bar{A} \cap F_{\alpha_1}) \cap F_{\alpha_2} = \bar{A} \cap F_{\alpha_2} = \bar{A}$. Continuing inductivily we get $\bar{A} \cap (\cap_{\alpha \in I} F_\alpha) = \bar{A}$. Since for any set $D\subset E \,\, D \cap D = D$ then we have $\bar{A} = \cap_{\alpha \in I} F_\alpha$. Q.E.D

Note: That $\bar{A} \subset F_\alpha \,\, \forall \alpha \in I$ with $A \subset F_\alpha \,\, \forall \alpha \in I$ is proved in Dangello&Seyfried, ${Introductory Real Analysis}$ on p. 248, Thm 11.3.